# If $X$ is Geometric$(\alpha/(n+\alpha))$ then show that $X/n$ has CGF $(s/n)- \log(1+(1-e^{s/n})n/\alpha) $, using the MGF

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Question**

Let $p = \frac{\alpha}{n + \alpha} $ , i.e. $X \sim$ Geometric$(p)$ where $X \geq 1$ and $0 < p < 1$. X has a probability generating function of $P_X(s) = \frac{ps}{(1-(1-p)s)}$. Let a random variable $Y \sim $ Exponential $(\alpha)$ where $Y > 0$ and $\alpha > 0$. $Y$ has moment generating function given by $m_y(s) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - s}$ for $s < a$

(i) Let $p = \frac{\alpha}{(n + \alpha)}$ , i.e. $X \sim $ Geometric$(\frac{\alpha}{n + \alpha})$ where $n$ is a positive constant. Show that the cumulant generating function of $W = \frac{X}{n}$ is given by:
$$\dfrac{s}{n} - \text{log}(1+ \dfrac{n}{\alpha}\Big(1-e^{\dfrac{s}{n}}\Big))$$

---

**Attempt**

> I know to find the cgf of some mgf you must take the log of it. I'm having difficulty with the process involved in doing this.
>
> So, X has a pgf of $P_X(s) = \frac{ps}{(1-(1-p)s)}$ , I sub in $p = \frac{\alpha}{(n + \alpha)}$ to get $\dfrac{\frac{\alpha}{(n + \alpha)}s}{(1-(1-\frac{\alpha}{(n + \alpha)})s)}$ while the question states; find the cgf of form $W=\frac{X}{n}$. Does my function become: $$\text{log}\Bigg[\dfrac{\frac{\alpha}{(n + \alpha)}s}{(1-(1-\frac{\alpha}{(n + \alpha)})s)}\Bigg] / n$$
>
> Which I would then solve down to the cgf given in the question? I can't get it to equal the required cgf.

---

**Thanks**

Comment: " Does my function become" Why would it? Please be specific, so that readers get the impression you thought about the problem before posting this.

Comment: @Did Because $W=\frac{X}{n}$ so I thought it would just be the pgf of X, divide by $n$. But I don't know. The work in the "attempt" section IS my 'thoughts on the problem.' Apologies for lack of clarity.

Comment: What is the formula to deduce the PGF of $cX$ from the PGF of $X$, already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting $X \sim $ Geo$\Big(\dfrac{\alpha}{n + \alpha})$ into $P_X(s) = \dfrac{\alpha s }{n + \alpha - ns}$, the mgf is $m_x(s) = \dfrac{\alpha e^s}{n+\alpha-ne^s}$

\begin{align}
 \log m_X(s)  &= \log\alpha + s - \log(n + \alpha - ne^s) \\[5px]
& = \log\alpha + s - \log(\alpha + n(1-e^s))\\[1px]
& = \log \alpha + s - \log(\alpha(1+\frac{n}{\alpha}(1-e^s))) \\[1px]
& = s - \log(1 + \frac{n}{\alpha}(1-e^s))\\[1px]
& = s - \log(1+\dfrac{n}{\alpha}(1-e^s))\\
\end{align}

Let $W = \dfrac{X}{n}$ therefore we have $\log m_w(s) = \log m_x(\dfrac{s}{n})$ which gives the desired cgf:
$$\dfrac{s}{n} - \log(1+\dfrac{n}{\alpha}(1-e^{\dfrac{s}{n}})$$